# Alert hidden text inside iframe using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Code inside iframe is loaded on windows load. However, contents of body loads after button click. And `div` with `id="headers"` is hidden but shown on another link click.

What I want is to access and alert **Some Id** on click search button.

How can I achieve this using **Javascript** or **jQuery**?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ubhsf03/)

Here is my Html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO</title>
  </head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div id="btn">
      <button id="btn-search">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="iframebox">
      <iframe id="messageiframe" srcdoc='
       #document

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
          <title>test</title>
        </head>

        <body class="full-height">

          <div id="preview">
            <ul id="list">
              <li class="mail"><a href="https://mail.gmail.com">Gmail</a></li>
              <li class="search"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li class="mail"><a href="https://mail.outlook.com">Outlook</a></li>
              <li class="search"><a href="https://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>

      <div id="all" style= "display: none;">
      <div id="headers">
      <font class="bold">Path</font>
      "Some path"
      <br>
      <font class="bold">doc Id</font>
      "Some Id"
      <br>
      <font class="bold">Recieved</font>
      "Me"
      </div>
      </div>

        </body>

        </html>'>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my Javascript code which is incomplete:

```
$('#btn-search').on('click', function() {
   // slight delay 
   setTimeout(function(){
         var links = [];
     var iframe = document.getElementById('messageiframe');
     iframe.contentWindow.onload = function(){
     var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
 };

   },100);
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "What I want is to access and alert Some Id without clicking link." When you  want to access Some Id?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.I want it on button search click.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on what you are trying to achieve when the search button is clicked? I am assuming on the click of the search button your wanting to show an alert or do some action and retrieve a value for an element that is inside the iframe? Is that correct? Just want to make sure I understand the question

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to alert text "Some Id" which is inside iframe <div> with id headers

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want? [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ubhsf03/5/)

```
$('#btn-search').on('click', function() { 
 // slight delay 
a= $('#messageiframe').contents().find('#headers ').find('font:eq(1)')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue
alert(a)
setTimeout(function(){
     var links = [];
 var iframe = document.getElementById('messageiframe');
 iframe.contentWindow.onload = function(){
 var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
};

},100);
});
```

Comment: you need to tell me how I can add id='someid' to that specific text using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @zennith. Is there a why to trigger this method after iframe contents are loaded. As iframe contents takes some time to load.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qLrohftb/1/

I modified your code slightly by removing the onload method is unnecessary. To get the inner document I modified your code to do this :

```
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

then once you have the document all you have to do is use innerDoc.getElementById or innerDoc.getElementByClassName or whichever method you want to use to retrieve the value from within the iframe. So in the example I get the element with className mail :

```
var element = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("mail")[0];
```

Then once I have the element I show the alert dialog.

Comment: I just want to alert "Some Id" which is inside "<div id = "headers">

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to get the element headers and output the html https://jsfiddle.net/ckruszynsky/qLrohftb/5/

Comment: nice. is there a way to extract specific text like "Some Id" from element.outerText ?